# WYSIWYG float image

Tags: magento-1.9, css, rwd-theme, wysiwyg, tabs

I don't know what's wrong that the image is not fitting the content div.
Is this a css problem? The image is on right float;

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're experiencing the classic issue of "The Great Collapse" (to borrow the phrase from Chris Coyier). Search for "The Great Collapse" on this page for more details: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

In the MRT theme, there is a Sass mixin that allows you to "clear floats". If you add this Sass to your theme, it should solve your issue:

```
#collateral-tabs .tab-content:after {
    @include clearfix;
}
```

This will apply CSS to the container of the tab content which should clear all floated children elements.

Comment: Hi Erik, I put the code on _clearfix.scss but it doesn't work.
the height of the tab-content should follow the content eventhough the height of image is long right?