# Table in WYSIWYG

Tags: magento-enterprise, rwd-theme

I added table tags on WYSIWYG in one of my attributes in my products.

But, this is what I got. I don't know what it is not inside the tab content div. I'm using the RWD Theme which is already has a tab content feature. I didn't use any plugin for this.

Please HELP!

[image]

Comment: can you please provide your live site link?

Comment: I cannot give it because its not yet live.

Comment: check the html part that you have created using css this problem will be solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alyssa, per my answer on [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/32964/2142), you need to have the element that is containing the table "clear" the floated table. If you read through the article [I linked to](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/), it should give you what you need to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Erik. Your comment helped me a lot because I found out that my table has attribute align="left" :) it's looking good now